# Applying function in new dataframe column based on value from another column

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, mean, calculation

I would like to apply rolling mean function in dataframe. I have more than one category (A and B in column Category) in dataframe, so I have to calculate rolling mean for each category and this is my issue.

Dataframe looks like below. The Rolling_Mean column is expected outcome.

```
Date        Category    Value   Rolling_Mean
01.01.2017  A           12,30   NaN
02.01.2017  A           12,50   NaN
03.01.2017  A           12,90   12,57
04.01.2017  A           13,10   12,70
05.01.2017  A           12,90   12,74
06.01.2017  A           13,55   12,88
07.01.2017  A           13,12   12,91
01.01.2017  B           1,14    NaN
02.01.2017  B           1,52    NaN
03.01.2017  B           1,74    1,47
04.01.2017  B           2,12    1,63
05.01.2017  B           1,75    1,65
06.01.2017  B           1,69    1,66
07.01.2017  B           1,35    1,62
```

to calculate rolling mean I use pandas rolling:

```
df['Rolling_Mean'] = df['Value'].rolling (window=3).mean()
```

but I'm not able to calculate rolling mean for more than one category.

I have tried to use numpy.where (below) to calculate this, but it works for only one category and I'm looking for solution, which works for 10 categories.

```
df['Rolling_Mean'] = np.where((df.Category == 'A'), df['Value'].rolling(window=3).mean(), 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `rolling`, but output is `Multiindex`, so need remove first level by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
#replace values to floats or use parameter decimal=',' in read_csv
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)


df['new'] = df.groupby('Category')['Value'].rolling(window=3, min_periods=3).mean()
              .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df)
          Date Category  Value Rolling_Mean        new
0   01.01.2017        A  12.30          NaN        NaN
1   02.01.2017        A  12.50          NaN        NaN
2   03.01.2017        A  12.90        12,57  12.566667
3   04.01.2017        A  13.10        12,70  12.833333
4   05.01.2017        A  12.90        12,74  12.966667
5   06.01.2017        A  13.55        12,88  13.183333
6   07.01.2017        A  13.12        12,91  13.190000
7   01.01.2017        B   1.14          NaN        NaN
8   02.01.2017        B   1.52          NaN        NaN
9   03.01.2017        B   1.74         1,47   1.466667
10  04.01.2017        B   2.12         1,63   1.793333
11  05.01.2017        B   1.75         1,65   1.870000
12  06.01.2017        B   1.69         1,66   1.853333
13  07.01.2017        B   1.35         1,62   1.596667
```

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Use `rolling` within a `groupby` context with `Category`.  To return the same index as the current dataframe, use `transform` with `rolling` embedded in a `lambda`

```
df.assign(
    Rolling_Mean=df.groupby('Category').Value.transform(
        lambda x: x.rolling(3).mean()
    )
)

          Date Category  Value  Rolling_Mean
0   01.01.2017        A  12.30           NaN
1   02.01.2017        A  12.50           NaN
2   03.01.2017        A  12.90     12.566667
3   04.01.2017        A  13.10     12.833333
4   05.01.2017        A  12.90     12.966667
5   06.01.2017        A  13.55     13.183333
6   07.01.2017        A  13.12     13.190000
7   01.01.2017        B   1.14           NaN
8   02.01.2017        B   1.52           NaN
9   03.01.2017        B   1.74      1.466667
10  04.01.2017        B   2.12      1.793333
11  05.01.2017        B   1.75      1.870000
12  06.01.2017        B   1.69      1.853333
13  07.01.2017        B   1.35      1.596667
```

---

**Note:**

If you want this result to persist, make sure to assign it to a variable

```
df = df.assign(
    Rolling_Mean=df.groupby('Category').Value.transform(
        lambda x: x.rolling(3).mean()
    )
)
```